# Meaning of "pushing it"

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of *pushing it*?

> Is a 19 year old too young for a 28 year old?
>
> Yeah 9 years is kinda pushing it, 'specially when the delta is like half her life.

Comment: Please consult a dictionary of your choice first, e.g. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pushing_it). You might also wish to support our proposed spin-off targeted specifically at [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Memming said, the idiom derives from *pushing the limit*, or trying to go beyond a limit.

But I don't think this makes its metaphorical meaning clear. It is always used to mean *hoping or pretending that something will work or fit or be acceptable when really it won't*.

So here it means pretending or hoping that an age difference of 9 years will work, but the speaker is suggesting that in reality 9 years is too much.

Answer (score 2):

It means pushing **the limit**. In your example, trying to force the limit of age difference as if there were a barrier.

Comment: I suspect that _pushing the limit_ is itself an idiom which is not necessarily clear to people whose first language is not English.